# Using a service to check if user authenticated, guard doesn't work

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I implement a firebase authentication page. So I set up a an Angular `service` `UserService` like so :

```
export class UserService {

  public authenticated: boolean;
  public error: any;
  public currentUser: User;

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.authenticated = false;
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(authenticated => {
      if (authenticated) {
        this.authenticated = true;
      }
    });
  }

  async loginWithGoogle() {
    try {
      const result = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
      this.authenticated = true;
      console.log(result.user);
    } catch (e) {
      this.error = e;
    }
  }

  async loginWithFacebook() {
    try {
      await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.FacebookAuthProvider());
      this.authenticated = true;
    } catch (e) {
      this.error = e;
    }
  }

}
```

This seems to work ok. But then when I try to access to a route protected by the following guard:

```
export class AuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(public userService: UserService, private router: Router) { }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    alert(this.userService.authenticated);
    if (this.userService.authenticated) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

But `this.userService.authenticated` is always `false`.

Is there a better way to do this? If not, what's wrong here? Maybe `authenticated` should be an `Observable` the guard subscribe to?

Answer (score 0):

I would a method get `authenticated()` instead of use a boolean attribute. Your boolean attribute will always have the same value. Try adding the following method:

```
get authenticated(){
  if(this.afAuth.auth.currentUser) {
  this.currentUser = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser
  return true;
  }
  else {
    return false
  };    
}
```

and then use `this.userService.authenticated()` instead of `this.userService.authenticated`

**EDIT**

I would also change the constructor of your **UserService** to:

```
constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.authenticated = this.authenticated()
  }
```

You have to keep in mind that you need to use the function authenticated() instead of the boolean authenticated. This is because in spite of the class being a singleton, the different components are not automatically notified of the changes in the variable.

Comment: It works but only for one time. If I refresh my page it says the user isn't connected anymore. I guess it's normal because the service is created again? What should I do to know if the user is still logged in? Use local storage?

Comment: I am not sure if it is normal. Look at my last edit and try to change the constructor. Also, make sure that you changed every apperarence of  this.userService.authenticated to the function this.userService.authenticated()

Comment: @Baptiste Arnaud , if find the answer helpful, could you please mark it as accepted for the time being?. That would be very much appreciated ;) .